# Securely separate reverse shell server connections for web devices

Tags: linux, security, ssh

I have a web-server on IOT device and Want to bypass any firewalls/routers so user would be able to have access to it.
For example we have web-device:80(linux/100 devices) and server(linux) to which these devices connecting using ssh -L servername.com, exposing their 80's ports to local ports of server. End user getting access to web-device located anywhere from anywhere, passing any routers and firewalls.

**The problem:** Imagine hacker is already inside server: Man in the middle problem.
How we can separate connections so even if server will be compromised?

**Idea 1** Setup NGINX with baseAuth reverse-port-tunneling multiplexer.

---

Here is one-click reverse ssh solution for connection:
https://gist.github.com/gdamjan/4586758

But how to separate 100 different ports forwarding through our server in case if server is already hacked (man-In-a-middle problem)

Answer (score 0):

containerization,  SSL/TLS encryption, Auth, and access control...
Ensure, these measures are applied.
I'm sorry, if this is not the answer you are looking for

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please describe what you mean by conteinerization?  Will all machines connect to containers?